# Export PDF with selected range of cells in active spreadsheet and send an e-mail

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range, export-to-pdf

:)

I am pretty new to Apps Script, but as google sheets functions started to be not enough for me, i thought i should give it a try.

I have a spreadsheet splitted to month sheets. I have already managed to export PDF of specified in scipt, range of cells, from choosed in function sheet. I made a button to send the pdf to specified in scrip e-mail, But i still cannot figure out few things:

- I need to script to work for active spreadsheet in active sheet tab ( so it should be variable)
- i want to generate PDF from 3 first rows and add to them selected active range of Cells (simple words i want to select few rows and from those rows export specified number of columns - for example i can choose 10 rows and want to export columns from A to G
- if I won't select rows then script should export entire sheet from columns A to G

Below i put my code ( which is partly thanks to this awesome forum).

```
function emailSheetRangeAsPDF(email, subject, body, sheetName) {

    var email = "filip.dzieciol@gmail.com"; // Enter the required email address here

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Wzornik"); // Enter the name of the sheet here

    var subject = subject;

    var body = body;

    // Base URL
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?".replace("SS_ID", ss.getId());

    /* Specify PDF export parameters
    From: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=3579
     */

    var url_ext = 'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
         + '&size=A4' // paper size legal / letter / A4
         + '&portrait=true' // orientation, false for landscape
         + '&fitw=true&source=labnol' // fit to page width, false for actual size
         + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false' // hide optional headers and footers
         + '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false' // hide page numbers and gridlines
         + '&fzr=true' // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
      //gid=sheetId                must be included. The first sheet will be 0. others will have a uniqe ID
         + '&ir=false'        // seems to be always false
         + '&ic=false'                 // same as ir
         + '&r1=0'     //  row 1 would be 0 , row 15 wold be 14
         + '&c1=0'   //  column 1 would be 0, column 8 would be 7   
         + '&r2=190'
         + '&c2=32'
         + '&gid='; // the sheet's Id

    var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + url_ext + sheet.getSheetId(), {
            headers : {
                'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        }).getBlob().setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf");

    // Uncomment the line below to save the PDF to the root of your drive. 
    //  var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(response).setName(sheet.getName() + ".pdf")

    if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > 0)
        GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
            htmlBody : body,
            attachments : [response]
        });
}
```

I tried:

- using getActiveSheet() but i keep getting errors
- using info from additional cells to change range of cells to export ( tried to deploy it in R1 C1 R2 C2), but i think my  knowledge of scripts is too poor. :(

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();` wil return the activesheet.

Comment: or, since you need the `sheet` variable later in the script: delete `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Wzornik")` and replace with `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()`. It's a variation on the comment by @pgSystemTester

Comment: Thank You both guys. I was tryung to use activesheet but i must missmatched something cause i kept getting errors. Now this part of a code works like a charm :) 

Thank You very much. Now i just need to sort how to make export only selected range of cells not defined in a code.